# Xcode unable to detect supabase-swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, supabase, supabase-database

I am trying to integrate supabase-swift framework in my app, I followed all their steps but unfortunately Xcode doesn't detect it.

How I installed?
SPM - Search by URL(https://github.com/supabase/supabase-swift.git) and then added the package successfully

Debugging:

- Clean Build folder
- Restart Xcode

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the cache under: ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm/ and reinstall